# Kafka state store Rock DB is fault tolerant?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Kafka state store Rock DB is fault tolerant , from the change log how can restore that piece of data which is not functioning ?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is... Kafka Streams will restore state automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restoration of all built-in storage engines in the Kafka Streams API is fully automated.

Further details are described at http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#fault-tolerant-state-stores, some of which I quote here:

> In order to make state stores fault-tolerant (e.g., to recover from machine crashes) as well as to allow for state store migration without data loss (e.g., to migrate a stateful stream task from one machine to another when elastically adding or removing capacity from your application), a state store can be continuously backed up to a Kafka topic behind the scenes. We sometimes refer to this topic as the state store’s associated changelog topic or simply its changelog. In the case of a machine failure, for example, the state store and thus the application’s state can be fully restored from its changelog. You can enable or disable this backup feature for a state store, and thus its fault tolerance.

Comment: So one of the Kafka stream process goes down so other  Kafka stream process will get the same state store which was down . Which is  automated only thing need enable change log

Comment: Yes.  And by default, changelogging is enabled.